# CodeIgniter Head Empty and content in body

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, frameworks, codeigniter-3

Hey i don't understand my website doesn't work i have don't do anything so i will explain

I got a 0 in top on my page now!
Google Chrome Explorator:[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bOQX.jpg)
https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisementrade.com%2F

`View/header.php: https://pastebin.com/7GqFYR75`

`View/homepage.php: https://pastebin.com/3htmFSmw`

`View/footer.php: https://pastebin.com/b3X9KScg`

`Controller/View.php: https://pastebin.com/cxCdcdEQ`

`Chrome viewer code: https://pastebin.com/Q8VYja5u`

I have check the encode UTF-8 and i have re encode UTF-8 with my sublime text but nothing change ... please need help

EDIT: FIXED

Comment: I think you need to load the view in your controller instead of the view, so you should have something like this:
$this->load->view('header');
$this->load->view('homepage',$data);

Comment: Must be something to do on your home page content

Comment: In your f$flash_month you have a lot of database $query which should be in a model function then passed through controller to view.

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: I have test for remove all code in home page and the zero number in top of page is still here ... https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wisementrade.com%2F

Answer (score 0):

I guess unclosed HTML tag cause this problerm. I found a few unclosed HTML tag in your View/header.php. Close it. try this.

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <!--o-->
        <?php
        //Session
        $customer_id = $this->session->userdata('customer_id');
        $user_type = $this->session->userdata('user_type');
        $statement = $this->session->userdata('timezone');

        ?>
        <!--o-->
        <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="<?php echo base_url('images/favicon.png'); ?>" />
        <meta name="author" content="Wise Men Trade" />
        <meta name="copyright" content="Copyright Notice ©2015 WisemenTrade Limited and licensors. All rights reserved." />
        <meta name="robots" content="all" />
        <!--o-->
        <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("css/bootstrap.min.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- Basic CSS -->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("css/style.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- Responsive CSS -->
        <link href="<?php echo base_url("css/responsive.css"); ?>" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <!-- Important Owl stylesheet -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("css/owl-carousel/owl.carousel.css"); ?>"/>
        <!-- Default Theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("css/owl-carousel/owl.theme.css"); ?>"/>
        <!-- MS DROP DOWN -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/msdropdown/flags.css'); ?>"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('css/msdropdown/dd.css'); ?>"/>

        <!-- Google Analytics -->
        <script>
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
            (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
            m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

            ga('create', 'UA-62333409-1', 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        </script>
        <!-- End Google Analytics -->

    </head>

<body>
<!--top-header-->
    <header>
        <div class="header_block">
            <!-- left -->
            <div class="block_left">
                <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
                    <img src="<?php echo base_url("images/log_wmt.png"); ?>" class="logo" width="130" height="130" alt="Logo Wise Men Trade" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
```

also in your Controller/View.php have a few unclosed div (`<div id="container">` and `<div class="block_content">`). check it and close it.

the last, make sure at the end of your Controller/View.php have a :

```
</body> <!-- end of body -->
</html> <!-- end of html -->
```

Comment: in my footer.php i got it

Comment: @Gentech-Digital , how about unclosed HTML tag in View/header.php (`<header>` and `<div class="header_block">`) . also in your view (`<div id="container">` and `<div class="block_content">`)

Comment: yes its closed in the rest on my code i will update in my original post for all

Comment: i've edit View/header.php code section at my answer. There's also unclose meta and <link> tag. try it. if there's still have a problerm. try to Cntrl + U your page using keyboard from browser to view source code. paste it in paste bin for troubleshot.

Comment: look my original post i have update for all content of file

Comment: can you provide pastebin of source code of you page on browser (push Cntrl + U to view source) .. note: not code from your file.php @Gentech-Digital

Comment: it's add on original post

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html), you could load multiple views in your controller, I think it doesn't work if you load it in the view, so you should have something like this:

```
<?php

class Page extends CI_Controller {

        public function index()
        {
                $data['page_title'] = 'Your title';
                $this->load->view('header');
                $this->load->view('menu');
                $this->load->view('content', $data);
                $this->load->view('footer');
        }

}
```

Comment: yep, i have comment meta because i load before doctype but i got a zero number in top of page check original post for chrome code viewer

Comment: check the documentation mate here https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html, I used it multiple times and it works.

Comment: dude the problem its the zero in the top of page check http://www.wisementrade.com/ as you can see a 0 on the top of page

Comment: lets try this add this in your controller ini_set('display_errors', 1);